# Issue while creating oracle connection in iReport tool

Tags: ireport

I am new to iReport tool. I am trying to create oracle connection but after entering all the required details when i click on Test connection button, it's showing an error like

[image: Error that is displaying while Test connection]

And the Exception looks like

```
Exception


Message:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
Level:
SEVERE
Stack Trace:
7
oracle.security.o3logon.C1.r(C1)
oracle.security.o3logon.C1.l(C1)
oracle.security.o3logon.C0.c(C0)
oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(O3LoginClientHelper)
oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.<init>(O3log.java:290)
oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:251)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:252)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:365)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:260)         com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.getConnection(JDBCConnection.java:140)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.test(JDBCConnection.java:449)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.jButtonTestActionPerformed(ConnectionDialog.java:335)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.access$300(ConnectionDialog.java:43)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog$4.actionPerformed(ConnectionDialog.java:290)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1039)
java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1091)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1089)
java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1419)
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1372)
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:801)
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:979)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.QuickStartPanel.jButton1ActionPerformed(QuickStartPanel.java:295)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.QuickStartPanel.access$200(QuickStartPanel.java:50)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.welcome.QuickStartPanel$2.actionPerformed(QuickStartPanel.java:124)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

I have already added the ojdbc.jar file in classpath and verified the username and password as well. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this after adding classes.12.jar file in class path of iReport or you can directly copy to

```
C:\Program Files\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.2.0\ireport\libs
```

1:-  To add new database click on databse icon -> JDBC Connection -> next.

2:-  Select  JDBC Driver class Oracle:-
         (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

3:- URL
      Syntax : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DatabaseName 
    Example1 : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl 
                                        (where orcl is SID of your Oracle)
    Example2 : jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.9:1521:orcl 
                                         (Remote database connection using IP)

4) Username & Password

5) Click on Test Connection.

Comment: Hi Sharad, Thanks for the reply. I tried above steps but still getting the same issue. Is there any specific location where i have to put classes12.jar file??

Comment: Thanks. Tried this also but not able to fix it. Its seems that problem is on my machine only because it is working fine on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i followed the below steps:

1. copy the **ojdbc6.jar** to ireports/libs.
2. Go To **Tools** > **Options**
   under the '**Classpath**' tab, you need to add the new ojdbc jar that you have added the libs folder.
3. restart **jaspersoft ireports designer** software.

now when you try to add the new database, oracle option is **black** instead of **red** which means its enabled.